# Issue with running a script from my desktop on Raspberry Pi

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a simple script that I wanted to run from my desktop to make it easier. I've put it into a .desktop file and when double clicked it opens a small window saying "This text file 'alerter.desktop' seems to be an executable script. What do you want to do with it?" with the options being "execute" "execute in terminal" "Open" " cancel". When clicking either execute option, the terminal flashes for a second and then disappears. The script works fine when typed into the terminal.

File contents:

```
    ...
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=alerter
    Comment=Starts alerter
    Exec=lxterminal -e ./docker_run.bash -c ./config/discord-alerts.yaml -a discord -w 
    https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/blahblahblah
    Terminal=true
    Type=Application
    Path=/home/pi/inventory-hunter
    ...
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your exec command in this way:

```
sh -c "lxterminal -e ./docker_run.bash -c ./config/discord-alerts.yaml -a discord -w"
```

Also set terminal to false.

Comment: It now opens the terminal to the inventory-hunter directory but doesn't actually run the script. It is progress though, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click on the file and select Properties
2. Choose Terminal Application in Open with option
3. If not present in the list ( Got to Customise -> Accessories -> Terminal)
4. Open File Manager
5. Go to Edit -> Preferences
6. Check the option "Don't Ask options on launch executable file"

Good to GO !!!!!